# Delete Fragment from backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a problem with cleaning of backstack. I call from Fragment A the Fragment B with :

```
 transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(((ViewGroup)(getView().getParent())).getId(), ScarsdaleScelta.newIstance());
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.commit();
```

The problem is that if in Fragment B I use navigation drawer and I change fragment without use the back button , the Fragment A remains in the backstack!
So if I press the back button the Fragment A overlaps the other Fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the fragment from the back stack yourself when navigating manually:

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Comment: Thank's , and where I need to put this code? In the onBackPressed() method in Fragment B? @user3249477

Comment: @Slaiv206 when you `use navigation drawer and I change fragment without use the back button`.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand where to put getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

Comment: @Slaiv206 I just told you. You put this line where you `use navigation drawer and I change fragment without use the back button`.